# How to stop tableview from indenting on edit while still having add/delete buttons?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview and when I press the edit button associated with it I do not want to have the cells indent but I still want the add/delete buttons to be inserted. When I have **tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath** return NO the cells still indent unless I have **editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath** return **UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone**. What is the easiest way to go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was watching "Session 432 - Mastering iPhone Table Views" from the Apple Developer - iPhone Development Foundation Videos session and at about 5:15 into it, they talk about

> -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

They even have images with the red deletable icon on the left (they appear inside the cell).

Unless they changed this in recent iOS releases, this should work.

I do want to thank you for mentioning tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath because it solved a problem I was having!  :)

jorj

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me without changing the editingStyle to none. I should mention this is for a regular non-grouped table.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but I can explain why `tableView:shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:` isn't working.  According to the comments on it:

```
// This method only applies to grouped style table views.
```